# Smart card Strong authentication / Verification ( fingerprints)

Tags: rsa, elliptic-curves, authentication, authenticated-encryption

I'm trying to make a strong authentication software and embedded software in a java card. I have found many papers and publications about the subject… too much information to process and I'm working on a very tight schedule, given that the Java card implementation I have supports ECC ( Elliptic curve cryptography ) and RSA, [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/439.pdf) has a very interesting secure method ( the proposed scheme can be viewed on pages 11, 12 and 13).

The problem is, I can't see how I can actually implement this scheme with RSA or ECC, or how to add the fingerprint factor to the equation (seeing how there are plenty of other papers and schemes for biometric authentication [paper1](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CF0QFjAF&url=http://danishbiometrics.files.wordpress.com/2009/08/t08_06.pdf&ei=IHJjU-aVBIiR0QWM1YHQDA&usg=AFQjCNF0g4QO6gUQXEHpBGZIputq3TsCdQ&sig2=O-OLDdcvD9F--E5asRHBAg&bvm=bv.65788261,d.d2k)). Does anyone have any idea about how I should go about implementing this ?